# SQL Server Jobs not running - Job Activity Monitor

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, jobs, transient-failure

I have several dozen SQL Server jobs that the Job Activity Monitor displays that do not appear to have been executed.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.6024.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        12.0.6024.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.19375
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.3.9600
```

None of the research I have done is providing me any clues as to why these jobs fail to execute. The description for all of these jobs is the same:

```
Status: Idle
Last Run Outcome: Unknown
Last Run: Never
Next Run: Not Scheduled
Category: Uncategorized
Runnable: No
Scheduled: about 1/2 Yes, about 1/2 No
```

I'm expecting to see that these jobs were successfully executed and completed.

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). But the version of SSMS is irrelevant here and that is what you posted. What is important is the version and edition of your database server instance.

Comment: Check the services on the server hosting your instance. Make sure that the SQL Server Agent is running.

Comment: Thanks @BillRuhl - It is running. Runs all day and each day I have this long list of jobs that haven't run.

Comment: Are you certain that they are scheduled to run? Your post says Next Run: Not Scheduled.

Comment: @BillRuhl If the job is complete or terminated, it also gets the 'not scheduled' status.